# Audio and video conferencing call in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, video-streaming, webrtc, videocall

I'm looking at how to do Audio and video conferencing call between Xamarin Forms (IOS and Android) to MVC Web and Windows Application using **Free Library like WebRTC or creating own Custom Conferenc Server using free open source only. Sorry to Twillio or OpenTok or quickblox or any other *paid framework*.**

Is there any SDK except WebRTC to do this using Xamarin Form?

I searched in the forum, and download WebRTC Sample but its doesn't work and found only very old answers. And nothing concrete about the operation.

If someone has done something like this, please share it with us.

Thank you all

Comment: https://vidyo.io/pricing/ is free ?

Comment: You could ask the library support team for more details .

Comment: checkout bigbluebutton https://bigbluebutton.org/

Comment: @Lucas-Vidyo.io is not free.

"Some accounts on Vidyo.io come with 4,000 free minutes. This should be enough for you to build your app and do preliminary testing and validation. Once the 4,000 minutes are consumed, you will need to sign up for service and pay for minutes used."

Comment: Most of calling third party library are not free . Here are some of  NuGet webrtc Packages which you can have a refer https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/webrtc .